# ineffable, weakly compact, and ? cardinal

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

In the online book, page 312,
http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235419485

what cardinal notion do we get, by requireing that X in the bottom of the page, is not only
stationary (yielding ineffable) or unbounded (weakly compact), but
even *club*.

Comment: I cannot see in my browser the answer, which was given an hour ago,and which said that the cardinal is "impossible".Where it disappeared?

Comment: The answer was deleted by its owner. I don't know why, but I am guessing that it has to do with the fact that instead of writing *here* a few lines, you ask people to download a .pdf and go to page 312. (This is an educated guess, this complaint appears on the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You get the very famous large cardinal called inconsistency.

**Theorem:** If any $f\colon [\kappa]^2\to 2$ has a homogeneous club then the club filter on $\kappa$ is an ultrafilter.

*Proof:* By a standard argument we also have the property for colourings with 3 colours. Now take an arbitrary $X\subseteq\kappa$ and define $f\colon [\kappa]^2\to 3$ by
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0;& x,y\in X\\ 1;& x,y\notin X\\ 2;&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Let $C$ be the homogeneous club for $f$. Clearly $C$ cannot have colour $2$ (since from two pairs, both of which have exactly one element of $X$, we can get a pair with both elements in $X$). But if $C$ has colour $0$ then $C\subseteq X$, putting $X$ into the club filter, and if $C$ has colour $1$ then $C\cap X=\emptyset$, putting $\kappa\setminus X$ into the club filter. $\square$

But since there are stationary costationary subsets of $\kappa$ (at least assuming choice), the club filter cannot possibly be an ultrafilter.

**Edit:** Here is a better argument showing that your proposed partition property is inconsistent.

*Proof:* The partition property clearly implies that any function $f\colon \kappa\to 2$ is constant on a club. Now apply this fact to the characteristic function of a stationary costationary subset of $\kappa$ to get a contradiction. $\square$

Comment: Which two pairs do you mean to take when $x\in X$ and $y\notin X$?

Comment: @user122424 If $C$ has colour 2 then we can find two disjoint pairs $\{x,y\},\{w,z\}$ from $C$ such that $x,w\in X$ and $y,z\notin X$. But then $f(x,w)=0$ contradicts $C$ having colour 2.

Comment: The "better argument" is clear to me,and nice. But I would like also to understand the original argument: How it follows form the existence of stationary and costationary set, that the club filter cannot be an ultrafilter??

Comment: @user3357120: Stationary set which is co-stationary does not contain a club. So you have a set and its complement neither contain a club, so neither is in the club filter. Therefore the club filter is not an ultrafilter.